# how to troubleshoot domain name before re-pointing Nameservers

Tags: dns, apache-httpd

suppose I have a site:

```
awesomefootball.com
```

hosted on a Linux server with db etc.. For testing, I know how to pull a copy to my MacBook and set up /etc/hosts file to let me test at

```
awesomefootball.local
```

and then I push up and then pull changes to implement.  However, I want to test out a site on another linux server it is being moved to, and obviously because of the remote location, I can't do it the same way.

Is there some way I can map awesomefootball.mynewserver.com over to the folder where the moved site will be using an apache .conf directive?  You'd think the site would work on the remote if it worked on my MacBook, but I want to know for sure before I repoint the Nameservers.

Comment: Have you already tried to just temporarily redirect `awesomefootball.com` to the new server using `/etc/hosts`? Ideally you don't want to change anything on the server itself as part of the cutover. If you must, you could add a `ServerAlias` to the vhost configuration.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion.  How would I make an etc/hosts file on my local machine successfully point to a remote server if the DNS is not set yet? - using the remote server IP?  As far as changing the /etc/hosts file on the remote linux server, I'm thinking that won't help.  Anyway I will research a .conf extra subdomain on a pointed domain and use that for my test first.  Just have to be very careful before I actually repoint nameservers...

Comment: You would set it up the way you normally do it `ip.ad.dress   awesomefootbal.com` on the client you're going to use to test the website. This way the only thing you're leaving out of the test is the DNS change which unfortunately you have to do.